# Ruby on Rails - Combine several JSONs from api call

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-4, merge

In my application, I need to do API-call to a client in order to get information about a product (I do it by giving `product_id`).

Their API only allows 1 `ID` at a time which would make the job many times harder.

what have in mind is to run the *API-call* several times and add the results to the view.

I did a small test with merging 2 `JSON` together, which worked fine. *Example:*

```
@products = data_1['data'] + data_2['data']
```

This was, of course, doing them by hand and simple. What I thought I could do was to do an `each do` on them and run the code, as below:

```
### CONTROLLER
product_id = Array(params[:product_id].split(','))
product_id.each do |id|
    uri = URI.parse("https://website.com/api?product_id=#{id}")

    request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri)
    request["Accept"] = "application/json"

    req_options = { use_ssl: uri.scheme == "https", }
    response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port, req_options) do |http|
      http.request(request)
    end
    data = JSON.parse(response.body)

    @products = data['data']
end


### VIEW
- @products.each do |product|
  %p= product.name
  %p= product.date
```

This doesn't give me any error, but in my view, I only see details for last `product_id param`. Same with if I move `@products = data['data']` out of the `each do`.

In a desperate attempt, I also tried with this with no luck:

```
@products = id.as_json.merge(data['data'])
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Ins't your code always overriding products, here?
    data = JSON.parse(response.body)
    products = data['data']

Comment: @RicardoJacas Thanks. Yeah it seems, it overrides all of them and only picks the last one only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was much closer to what I had in mind. I need to run `map` on the `variable` itself, like below:

```
### CONTROLLER
product_id = Array(params[:product_id].split(','))

@products = product_id.map { |id|
  request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri)
  request["Accept"] = "application/json"

  req_options = { use_ssl: uri.scheme == "https", }
  response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port, req_options) do |http|
    http.request(request)
  end
  data = JSON.parse(response.body)
  data['data']
}
```

hope it helps someone :)